# How do you set up Shipping Profiles like Etsy has

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, multishipping

I need the ability to set up shipping profiles in magento.  I can't understand how to do this, I can't find extensions to do this because I seem to get irrelevent results on magento connect.

I need to be able to charge $2.99 for the first product and $.25 for each additional product.  The buyer must be able to select different items, I was only able to figure out how to apply it to the same item which is ridiculously limiting. I must be doing something wrong.  This must also apply only to domestic shipping.

I then need an international profile which would charge $5.99 for the first product and $.99 for each additional product.  This must also be applied to all products, not just the same product.

I would also like to display the shipping costs on the item description page so it's not just a suprise when they go through the hassle of the checkout just to say "That's too much"

Is there a way to set this up?  Or is there an extension I could use?  (Free or paid)

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there an extension I could use? (Free or paid)

Yes.  Look at Amasty or webshopapps.  They both have suites of extensions that will fit the bill.